# Sometimes Flash freezes in fullscreen mode. How can I just close it?

Tags: 12.10, flash, youtube

Almost every time I use YouTube in fullscreen it freezes and doesn't let me back to the desktop.

I want to know if it's possible close to it through the terminal or something like that. Something easier then reboot the PC all the time.

Comment: Can you do Ctrl+Alt+F1?  You can comeback using Ctrl+Alt+F7.

Comment: (1) This looks like a bug in Adobe Flash, and therefore should not be posted as a question in Ask Ubuntu.  Instead, you should report it to Adobe. (2) Have you tried using the HTML5 version of YouTube?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug with Flash even though it does involve Flash. Let's see if OP comes back with more information such as the browser, hardware specs (CPU, RAM, graphics card, etc). If you're sure it's a bug, could you please provide the appropriate link?

Comment: I have (probably) the same problem. Sometimes flashplayer hangs in fullscreen (only noticed it on youtube), it mostly seems to happen with 1080p, but probably depends on load. For me it have occurred both on my stationary (i7, ati with fglrx 13.0) and my laptop (i5, integrated graphics).

I can always solve the problem by bringing up a terminal on another desktop and kill flashplayer.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F2 to open command line, right? It's works, but when back with Ctrl+Alt+F7, just show a grey or white screen.

Comment: Probably it's a Flash+Ubuntu problem, because didn't notice that on Windows, for example. And back again to my question, I already tried to solve it, but now I just want to know is there an way to kill the Flash to avoid to reboot all the time.


The PC is a Dell 15R, with i5 and without dedicated graphic card (I think).

I already tried open the command line (Alt+Ctrl+F2) and "killall chrome" and "killall adobeflash", nothing seems to work.

I tried to "restart" compiz with "compiz --replace", it's back with something about "visual" doesn't work or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

**If you can open the terminal :**

try `pkill -9 firefox`

or change Firefox , if you are using another browser  .

Answer (score -1):

you see what happens is that adobe flash did not really freeze it's just that your ubuntu locked itselft. What you have to try is to make sure that your ubuntu does not lock when it's inactive OR whenever it locks go to terminal through ctrl+alt+f1 and type in killall[space][browser] e.g *killall chrome*.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)